# Prevent open dialog onClick of a button with react-dropzone

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-dropzone

I use `react-dropzone` to upload files.
When files are uploaded, they are stored in an array, which I use to list all items uploaded.

I added a button on the side of each `li` to delete the specific file from the array.

It works well, but opens a dialog to select a new file each time I delete one.

Is it possible to prevent this behaviour ?

Here is a simplified sandbox. The delete button must only console log, not open dialog : [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/distracted-surf-j9thgj?file=/src/App.tsx)

Here is the simplified code :

```
import { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import Dropzone from "react-dropzone";
import * as React from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [files, setFiles] = useState([{ name: "test" }]);

  const handleDrop = () => {
    console.log("dropped");
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>React Typescript Tailwind CSS started</h1>

      <Dropzone onDrop={handleDrop}>
        {({ getRootProps, getInputProps }) => (
          <div style={{ border: "2px solid black", height: "100px" }}>
            <div>
              <div {...getRootProps()}>
                <input {...getInputProps()} />

                <button>Select a file</button>

                {files && files.length > 0 && (
                  <ul>
                    {files.map((file) => (
                      <li key={file.name} className="relative w-fit">
                        {file.name}
                        <button onClick={() => console.log("delete")}>
                          delete
                        </button>
                      </li>
                    ))}
                  </ul>
                )}
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        )}
      </Dropzone>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Where is the dialog? Can you create a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example? A running demo using https://codesandbox.io/ is better.

Comment: @LinDu hey, I added a simplified sandbox. Hope it helps. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Set noClick as true to prevent the dialog from opening every time someone clicks on any area inside the div:

`const {getRootProps, getInputProps, open} = useDropzone({noClick: true})`

2. When you have to open the dialog use this:
   `onClick={open}`

Comment: works perfectly. Tanks

Comment: Glad to know that it worked for you :>

Answer (score 1):

See [Using `open()` on Click](https://github.com/react-dropzone/react-dropzone/#using-open-on-click)

> If you bind a click event on an inner element and use `open()`, it will trigger a click on the root element too, resulting in the file dialog opening twice. To prevent this, use the `noClick` on the root:

Choice 1. Use `useDropzone({ noClick: true })` hook

```
import { useState } from 'react';
import { useDropzone } from 'react-dropzone';
import * as React from 'react';

export default function App() {
    const [files, setFiles] = useState([{ name: 'test' }]);
    const { getRootProps, getInputProps, open } = useDropzone({ noClick: true });

    return (
        <div className="App">
            <h1>React Typescript Tailwind CSS started</h1>
            <div style={{ border: '2px solid black', height: '100px' }}>
                <div {...getRootProps()}>
                    <input {...getInputProps()} />
                    <button onClick={open}>Select a file</button>
                    {files && files.length > 0 && (
                        <ul>
                            {files.map((file) => (
                                <li key={file.name} className="relative w-fit">
                                    {file.name}
                                    <button
                                        type="button"
                                        onClick={() => {
                                            console.log('delete');
                                        }}>
                                        delete
                                    </button>
                                </li>
                            ))}
                        </ul>
                    )}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/so-76801534-99lv4p)

Choice 2. Pass `noClick` prop to `Dropzone` component.

```
import { useState } from 'react';
import Dropzone from 'react-dropzone';
import * as React from 'react';

export default function App() {
    const [files, setFiles] = useState([{ name: 'test' }]);

    const handleDrop = () => {
        console.log('dropped');
    };

    return (
        <div className="App">
            <h1>React Typescript Tailwind CSS started</h1>

            <Dropzone onDrop={handleDrop} noClick>
                {({ getRootProps, getInputProps, open }) => (
                    <div style={{ border: '2px solid black', height: '100px' }}>
                        <div>
                            <div {...getRootProps()}>
                                <input {...getInputProps()} />
                                <button onClick={open}>Select a file</button>
                                {files && files.length > 0 && (
                                    <ul>
                                        {files.map((file) => (
                                            <li key={file.name} className="relative w-fit">
                                                {file.name}
                                                <button onClick={() => console.log('delete')}>delete</button>
                                            </li>
                                        ))}
                                    </ul>
                                )}
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                )}
            </Dropzone>
        </div>
    );
}
```

[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/so-76801534-2-ks4hxk?file=/src/App.tsx)